# Key signature in tab books

Tags: scales, key

I have a few tab books that also have regular music notation. I go through them and write the note names above the notes and try and make some sense of it. Then I take the notes that are emphesised and also on beats and circle them. So now I have a set of notes that are "important to the song" . I plug them into a scale finder and voila ! the key signature that is in the book is not even close to (minor , ect ) 
Heres an example . Chords A7,D7,E7 Notes ACDEG
But the Key signature is G but the A seems to be the dominant note.Also Being a Blues tune the I - IV -V leans to a A Scale
What might I be doing wrong ?

Comment: Could you post a the first few bars of the tab? There is most likely a reason, but without seeing it, it just sounds like a print error.

Comment: Thanks, But thats a lot of work for this tune. Someone might be able to answer it without that.

Comment: Without more information you are just asking does it make sense that the key of G major only uses the chords A7 D7 E7. We don't even know if that is the actual progression because we don't know what song it is.

Comment: could we get you to add a photo?

Comment: Dorian A bears the G major signature, though I do not know whether any blues use of that mode was deliberate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the notes belong to A pent. min. There should probably be an open key sig. as the key refers to C major.  With chords of A7, D7 and E7, as you state, it's firmly in A blues. No other key has I, IV and V as those. If there are no Fs or F#s, then they won't get played anyway. The writer may as well have put Fb in the key sig! A lot of tab writers are pretty clueless of proper music convention - they don't use or need it - so expect inaccuracies. If it's been generated by a computer program, unless the program has been given salient clues, it has to make up its own mind...